# How to execute a .sh file from windows batch file in wsl

Tags: batch-file, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, erpnext

I am trying to execute a .sh file inside ubuntu from .bat file inside windows.

I have tried following code

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Ubuntu\Ubuntu"
start ubuntu1804.exe run ErpStartupService.sh
```

and my ErpStartupService.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo service mysql start
sudo service nginx start
sudo service redis-server start
sudo service supervisor start
cd /home/frappe/frappe-bench
sudo bench start
read -p "$*"
```

if i am running ErpStartupService.sh as ./ErpStartupService.sh from ubuntu terminal everything is executing as expected.but if i run bat file terminal is disappearing and not able to understand what is happening.i am using ubuntu 18.0.4 as wsl

Answer (score 5):

You are almost there. Don't use `start`.

```
bash.exe -c ./ErpStartupService.sh
```

or

```
ubuntu1804.exe run bash -c ./ErpStartupService.sh
```

Just play a bit

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your reply.i think its working upto sudo service supervisor start.
is there any issues on these two commands?
cd /home/frappe/frappe-bench
sudo bench start

Comment: sudo bench start looks strange for me but I don't know this tool. If it runs right inside the WSL session I don't see reasons why they wouldn't outside. Maybe you can add login session to bash: `bash -l -c ./ErpStartupService.sh`